# How to synchronize two DataGridViews?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two DataGridViews both are binding with same datasource. I would like to synchronize both grid with filtering, sorting, (etc).
(I.e)
If i sort the dataGridView1 column, the changes will be automatically reflect in dataGridView2.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sorted(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You can use [DataGridView.CellValueChanged Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged(v=vs.110).aspx) to update the other DataGridView